# TYPO3 Fluid Templates Variables Bit-Operator

Tags: typo3, fluid

I wonder how to do some bit-wise math in a Fluid template. Like a bit-wise AND:

```
<f:if condition="{var & 2}"> ... </f:if>
```

But the `{var & 2}` expression isn't evaluated and remains as a string.

I couldn't find a viewhelper so far. I guess I have to write one?

Comment: why do you think there is a bit-operator? have you any hints or documentation about it?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I don't know, that's why I try to find out... If any of those operators are documented, then where?

Comment: at the [documentation of the if-VH](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/If.html). there is no bit operator. Though you need to make your own viewhelper for bitoperations. or you ask in slack for someone who already did.